# Не могу поставить бота на сервер игры Го

Tags: ubuntu, бот

Я не могу поставить [бота](http://pachi.or.cz/)  на сервер игры Го.

Получаю такую ошибку

```
kl@ox:~/kgsBot/kgsGtp$ java -jar kgsGtp.jar pachi.config
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
sep 15, 2015 2:01:09 AM com.gokgs.client.gtp.GtpClient main
FINE: KGS GTP Client v3.5.20 starting up
sep 15, 2015 2:01:10 AM com.gokgs.client.gtp.GtpClient main
SEVERE: Fatal exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./pachi": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at com.gokgs.client.gtp.GtpClient.main(kgsgtp:918)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 4 more
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Человеческим языком же написано :)

> Cannot run program "./pachi": error=13, Permission denied

Нет прав на запуск `./pachi`